# How do i set a new browser instance in to a full screen mode, not as maximize in protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, cucumberjs

During the test when the application start, after a while a new browser opens.
How do I set the new browser instance as full screen not as maximize?

Answer (score 4):

For the Google Chrome browser, you can add `--start-fullscreen` argument to start in fullscreen mode, like if the user had pressed F11 right after startup. Add it to the `chromeOptions` object in the `protractor.conf.js` file.

```
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--start-fullscreen']
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript executor, you can do something like

```
max_width, max_height = driver.execute_script("return [window.screen.availWidth, window.screen.availHeight];")

browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(max_width, max_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before getting the available width and available height and then the window size as suggested by @demouser123

You need to switch the handle to new browser instance, otherwise browser.driver will keep pointing to first browse.